# Why scopes between directives not connecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have directive for dropdown:
dropdown.html:

```
<div class='dropdown-container' ng-class='{ show: listVisible }'>
    <div class='dropdown-display insetShadow' ng-click='show();' ng-class='{ clicked: listVisible }'>
        <span ng-if='!isPlaceholder'>{{ display }}</span>
        <span class='placeholder' ng-if='isPlaceholder'>{{ placeholder }}</span>
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
    </div>
    <div class='dropdown-list'>
        <div>
            <div ng-repeat='item in list' ng-click='select(item)' ng-class='{ selected: isSelected(item) }'>
                <div>
                    <span>{{property !== undefined ? item[property] : item}}</span>
                    <i class='fa fa-check'></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
.directive('dropdown', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "templates/dropdown.html",
        scope: {
            placeholder: "@",
            list: "=",
            selected: "=",
            property: "@",
            value: "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.listVisible = false;
            scope.isPlaceholder = true;

            scope.select = function(item) {
                scope.isPlaceholder = false;
                scope.selected = item[scope.value];
                scope.listVisible = false;

            };

            scope.isSelected = function(item) {                                                                                      
                return item[scope.value] === scope.selected;
            };

            scope.show = function() {
                scope.listVisible = true;
            };

            $rootScope.$on("documentClicked", function(inner, target) {
                if(!$(target[0]).is(".dropdown-display.clicked") && !$(target[0]).parents(".dropdown-display.clicked").length > 0) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.listVisible = false;
                    });
                }
            });                     

            scope.$watch('selected', function(value) {
                if(scope.list != undefined) {
                    angular.forEach(scope.list, function(objItem) {
                        if(objItem[scope.value] == scope.selected) {
                            scope.isPlaceholder = objItem[scope.property] === undefined;
                            scope.display = (objItem[scope.property].toLowerCase().indexOf('пусто') == -1) ? objItem[scope.property] : '';
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            scope.$watch('list', function(value) {
                angular.forEach(scope.list, function(objItem) {
                    if(objItem[scope.value] == scope.selected) {
                        scope.isPlaceholder = objItem[scope.property] === undefined;
                        scope.display = objItem[scope.property];
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    }
}])
```

Usage:

```
<dropdown placeholder='' list='actions' selected='' property='title' value='id' style='width:150px;'></dropdown>
```

Attributes:
list => array of objects to display in dropdown, basic data.
selected => variable in scope to save selected in dropdown value (value from field of selected object).
property => field of objects in array to display like label in dropdown for user to select value.
value => field of object to be like an selected value.

Example:

```
$scope.savedValue;
$scope.dataList= [{
    'title' :'text text text 111',
    'id':'1'
}, {
    'title' :'text text text 222',
    'id':'2'
}, {
    'title' :'text text text 333',
    'id':'3'
}, {
    'title' :'text text text 444',
    'id':'4'
}, {
    'title' :'text text text 555',
    'id':'5'
}];
```

Not working(don't know why):

```
<dropdown placeholder='' list='dataList' selected='savedValue' property='title' value='id'></dropdown>
```

Working:

```
$scope.obj = {};
$scope.obj.savedValue;
<dropdown placeholder='' list='dataList' selected='obj.savedValue' property='title' value='id'></dropdown>
```

Comment: Simplify your example to minimum

Comment: And your issue is? Sorry but throwing 50 lines of code and saying that your directive 'does not work' means nothing to me.

Comment: When I use <dropdown> in other directive when I use scope variable in 'selected' to save selection it not working.

Comment: I copied your code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/b8Nc30LYhSmQRe72rUK7?p=preview What isn't working?

Comment: I use <dropdown> in other directives template. And pass to 'selected' variable of directive sccope. It not working like on plnkr.

Comment: Can you replicate it in Plunker? Would be much easier for people to help.

Comment: I make new plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ULiACQoPnz80zrOOsGAV?p=preview   it working. In my project I use ui-routing. directives in different states. Could in be issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usual dot issue. You can not modify i.e. simple  string from nested scope.
In your plunk, lets make some modifications, add second dropdown:

```
<dropdown  ng-repeat="i in [1, 2]" style='width:150px;' placeholder='' list='dataList' selected='savedValue' property='title' value='id'></dropdown>
selected: {{ savedValue }}
```

What one is expected too see is two connected dropdowns - but this doesnt happen. Ng-repeat creates nested scope for each element, savedValue is passed to child scopes successfully, but child scopes can not modify it.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Nd0wDm6chq6CKDlucRfZ?p=preview

So you need to use some wrapper:

```
<dropdown  ng-repeat="i in [1, 2]" style='width:150px;' placeholder='' list='dataList' selected='o.savedValue' property='title' value='id'></dropdown>
selected: {{ o.savedValue }}
```

And then it works:
http://plnkr.co/edit/HMWBTrW9egFc663uniiO?p=preview

Comment: Useful for future. I will remember. But it not a problem, scope variable changing and I display it on {{  }} operator, but can't catch on $scope.$watch => not working, don't know why. If I use object wrapper as suggested it work, but I wish to figure why do not working without wrapper object.